# How to serialize everything

Tags: c#, serialization

One of my friends has an interesting problem. He has some complex objects stored in his session for some logging reason he has to serialize them all and persist them in the db.

We have tries XMLSerializer, NewtonSoft but we are unable to serialize 'everything'. Is there a way one can serialize anything and everything in an object?

For example, we are unable to serialize IList, IEnumerable, etc. type of properties.

Any suggestions at all?

Comment: **Side note**: it's a bad idea to keep complex objects on the session. It's a bad idead to *keep* complex objects at all. Retrieve them, process/manipulate/output, update/save and you're done.

Comment: Well, it's not my code and this requirement just came up right now :) You are right in saying that we should refactor this code but that's a long road :)

Comment: These types cannot be serialized, because they don't have any explicit data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haha I giggled when I read the question "How to serialize everything"

I think you could create a custom JsonConverter which could detect "Unserializable" types and convert them to something "serializable", or in this case you could even write the object yourself.

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    if (object is INotSerializableDontEvenTry)
    {
        INotSerializableDontEvenTry dontEvenTry = (INotSerializableDontEvenTry) object;
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName(dontEvenTry.Name);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, dontEvenTry.Value);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
    else
    {
        base.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
    }
}
```

Search for `JSON.NET Implementing Custom Serialization` and you will find a lot of resources that could help you with that. I'm just writing this off of my head (and some google) and I didn't test it, but it should work...

Comment: Ended up using Json.net and newton soft!. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can't serialize "everything" because not everything is serializable.

In particular, you can't serialize an interface, like IList.

Comment: Awww.. really? this is so dissapointing =(. I was expecting to serialize my drums at home, bring them to the office in a pen-drive, and then deserialize them here to play some tunes at lunch time =(

Comment: So I was just thinking whether my friend can make additional properties at runtime using reflection and then populate these newly made properties from "I" type of properties but then deserialization logic would be cumbersome too.

Comment: @HighCore Or... you could serialize yourself instead, so you could send yourself home at lunch time and play some tunes there, and take a nap before going back to work.

Comment: A reference to an interface like IList is only a reference to something that implements the functionality of the interface. It is behavior only - no data. There may be  nothing at all to serialize.

Answer (score 1):

I believe only concrete types maybe serialized - i.e. convert IList, IEnumerable etc. to "List" types in your value-objects that are to be serialized.

Comment: No I cannot change the type definitions.

Comment: It is not possible to serialize interface types - and that's unfortunately the way it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can try wrapper-serialization with something like this:

```cs
[Serializable] public class Wrapper{
    public readonly object InnerObject;
    public Wrapper(object InnerObject){
        this.InnerObject = InnerObject;
    }
}
```

But please DO NOT try to serialize unmanaged stuff or anything containing unmanaged code like those ones:

```cs
Stream
Process
Method
Task
Thread
delegate
...
```

but managed code can be fine.